# How to stop application,application server,node,nodeagent in websphere

Tags: java, websphere, solaris

our java application is deployed in web sphere in solaris server, and in the solaris some upgrades need to be performed, before they perform upgraded i need to stop the application in websphere.

so please help what are the things i need to stop in a sequence and how?, there will be a application,application server,node,nodeagent,httpserver,dmgr all those.

tell me how can stop and start above all in a sequence.

Thanks, in advance!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual shutdown approach would be to shutdown in this order

1. WebServer(s)
2. Application(s)
3. Appserver(s)
4. Nodeagent(s) (this represents the node too in your question)
5. Dmgr(s) (usually only one see this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/welcadminagents.html))

Then starting back up would be the same list but like this:

1. Dmgr(s)
2. Nodeagent(s)
3. Appserver(s)
4. Application(s)
5. Webserver(s)

You could step through most of these stop activities on the WebSphere Application Server console ... and for starting you have to get the dmgr running from the command line before you can access the console and you have to start the nodeagent from the command line to do the start activities from the console, but there is no built in way from a to z to make this all happen in a defined sequence, other than perhaps configuring operating services with dependencies via [wasservice](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rins_wasservice.html) etc and that varies between Windows, Linux, Solaris... there is some information in [WebSphere Application Server V8: Administration and Configuration Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247971.html?Open) in 7.9.2 about how to do this in Linux/Unix so most people write a bring up script and a shutdown script that is custom to their environment to call lower level scripts provided, and need to add delays or other logic to sequence to their desired level of control ... see some of these [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tadm_startstop.html) but basically:

to stop

- apachectl stop (to stop webserver)
- stopServer (or see [-stopservers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_stopnode.html) on stopNode command below)
- stopNode
- stopManager

and to start

- startManager
- startNode (depending on how you have the [Monitoring policy](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/urun_rmonitorpol.html) set this could start the  appservers for you and how you have the applications set to start or not will handle the applications (default is to have apps start when server starts)
- apachectl start (to start webserver)

You could get even more complex with using scripting in [wsadmin](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_commandline.html) for the native WebSphere Application Server elements, but there have been courses and books published on that subject, so I don't think it can fully be explained here.